# Commutation relation between EM field operators that are seperated by a half-reflected mirror?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-optics

Assume that we have a 1-D space seperated by a half-reflected mirror. The mirror is placed at $z=0$, and both sides of the mirror are vacuum(not vacuum state). Now I want to quantize the vector potential $A(z, t)$, following the conventional method we may expand the field as a series of plane waves:

for $z<0$, $A^{(+)}(z, t)=\int_0^{\infty}d\omega\ e^{i\omega t}(a_L(\omega)e^{i\omega z}+a_R(\omega)e^{-i\omega z})$

for $z>0$, $A^{(+)}(z, t)=\int_0^{\infty}d\omega\ e^{i\omega t}(b_L(\omega)e^{i\omega z}+b_R(\omega)e^{-i\omega z})$

In order to obey canonical commutation relationships, it is natural that $[a_{L/R}(\omega), a^+_{L/R}(\omega^\prime)]=\delta(\omega-\omega^\prime)$, $[b_{L/R}(\omega), b^+_{L/R}(\omega^\prime)]=\delta(\omega-\omega^\prime)$, the left are zeros.

On the other hand, we obtain that $b_R(\omega)=\sqrt{R}\ b_L(\omega)+\sqrt{T}\ a_R(\omega)$ from the input-output relationship of mirrors, in which $R$ and $T$ are reflectivity, transmissivity, respectivily. Then we see a contradiction:

1. $[b_R(\omega), a_R^+(\omega^\prime)]=0$ from canonical commutation relationship only;
2. $[b_R(\omega), a_R^+(\omega^\prime)]=[\sqrt{R}\ b_L(\omega)+\sqrt{T}\ a_R(\omega), a_R^+(\omega^\prime)]=\sqrt{T}\delta(\omega-\omega^\prime)\neq0$, in which the first '=' substitudes output field amplitudes for input ones.

Anyone point out what the error is?

[image]

reference: [Quantum theory of optical pulse propagation through an absorbing and dispersive slab](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.55.1347)

Comment: What do you mean "from the commutation relation only"? How can you compute that commutation relation *without* substituting in for b in terms of the a's, like you did in 2? 1 is wrong, and 2 is correct, and if you compute $[b,b^{\dagger}]$ by substituting in for the a's, it will come out correctly as a delta function after using that $R+T=1$.

Comment: @march "from the commutation relation only" means that for $z_1<0$ and $z_2>0$, $[A(z_1, t), A(z_2, t)]=0$ and $[A(z_1, t), \Pi (z_2, t)]=0$ hold, because canonical commutation relationship gives $[A(z, t), \Pi (z^{\prime}, t)]=i\hbar \delta(z-z^{\prime})$, in which $z$ and $z^{\prime}$ can be any point in the whole space. Is there any problem here?

Comment: After a carefully review, I confirm that 1 is wrong and 2 is correct, while 2 doesn't conflict with commutation relationships between fields $[A(z_1, t), A(z_2, t)]=0$ and $[A(z_1, t), \Pi (z_2, t)]=0$, the later two don't support solution 1 only.